# Kinetic.js "Object has no method batchDraw"

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

I'm trying to set up a basic Kinetic.js application. I keep getting strange errors all over the place, and there are hardly any references for Kinetic.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{    
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'canvas',
        width: 700,
        height: 434
    });

    var cursorCanvas = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var drawingCanvas = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var outerCircle = new Kinetic.Circle({
        radius: settings.size,
        strokeWidth: 4,
        stroke: "#000"
    });

    var innerCircle = new Kinetic.Circle({
        radius: settings.size,
        strokeWidth: 2,
        stroke: "#fff"
    });

    $(stage.getContent()).on('mousemove', function (e)
    {
        var pos = stage.getMousePosition();
        outerCircle.setAbsolutePosition(pos.x,pos.y);
        innerCircle.setAbsolutePosition(pos.x,pos.y);
        cursorCanvas.batchDraw(); //This throws an error
    }); 

    cursorCanvas.add(outerCircle);
    cursorCanvas.add(innerCircle);

    stage.add(cursorCanvas);
});
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'batchDraw'

Also, whenever I try to add a second layer to my stage:
    stage.add(drawingCanvas);
    stage.add(cursorCanvas);

I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Type error kinetic.min.js:28

Any help? :)

Comment: I'm using the CDN version. That's the website I referenced as well.

Comment: When I use the downloaded Kinetic, I get Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getMousePosition'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error looks like Kinetic expects to concatenate a "#" with the id of an element to locate that element with JQuery--only to find that id isn't available.

Try setting your event handler to

```
stage.on('contentMousemove', function (e)
{
    //Stuff
});
```

Comment: No more errors, but the event handler isn't called either. :\

Comment: No errors means my work here is done. Just kidding. I made an edit. Try a different event.

Comment: The event is being called, but I'm getting 
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getMousePosition' on the stage now.

Comment: According to the [docs](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Stage.html), I think you want to call `getPointerPosition()`.

Comment: Thanks you so much for the hand-holding!

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project! And if it's a game, I better get to play for free.